# How to deserialize JSON using GSON with common base class

Tags: android, serialization, gson, retrofit2

I have a json which looks like this

```
{
    user:{
            name:abc
            email:a@bc.com
            .....    
          }
    responseCode:1
    responseMessage:Done
}
```

I am using Retrofit 2 with GSON convertor. The 2 parameters 
**responseCode** and **responseMessage** appear in every JSON. The differentiating parameter is the "user"

So I created a class

```
class BaseResponse {
    public int responseCode;
    public String responseMessage; 
}
```

Then the rest of the POJOS extend something like this:

```
class User extends BaseResponse {
    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

Problem is, GSON does not deserialize the "user" part. 
I figured I had to write a **deserializer** .

```
return new JsonDeserializer<T>() {
            @Override
            public T deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                    throws JsonParseException {

                JsonObject jsonObject  = json.getAsJsonObject();
                int        messageCode = jsonObject.get("responseCode").getAsInt();

                if (messageCode == 1) {
                    **// What do I do now?**
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
```

The problem is, GSON returns me the User object with the user object elements all null.

I am kind of in a fix. Is there anyway this is possible? Either I get the child class stuff by doing `JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("user");` or the parent. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to make these 3 classes then you don't need to write a deserializer.

```
public abstract class BaseResponse {
    public int responseCode;
    public String responseMessage; 
}

public class UserResponse extend BaseResponse {
    private User user;
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email; 
}
```

then you just say `Call<UserResponse> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);`

Comment: so ya I tried it. I had to make `User extend UserResponse` otherwise it wasn't working. Anyway thanks!